# Get post meta value outside of the loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I'm working on an extra function to list different stuff,

My function looks like: "display all hotels for a specific city"
-> hotels is as CPT and CITY as custom Tax. So for exemple, lets display all hotels in Paris.

```
function test($cpt,$taxonomy = 0) {
   $args (...)
   $query (...)
   while {...}
}
```

So I go to query different custom posts types, with or without a taxonomy. Until here, everything is OK.

But is it possible to get some data from this $taxonomy (city/paris) without creating a new query? Like I want to get custom field called "area_singular" linked to the `$taxonomy` passed in the function? The title of it, etc.?

P.S. The value of `$taxonomy` is passed by

```
$term = get_queried_object();
test('custom_post',$term);
```

P.P.S. Actually i have an other function, where i pass this custom field, & title in the function like `test('cpt',$term,$custom_field,$title);` but I'm sure there is a way to get the data without passing them by the function.

EDIT: With 
`$taxonomy->post_title`
I can get the title, 
so how can I get the custom field the same way?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to get the value of a field attached to a custom taxonomy term? Example: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/#notes

Comment: Hello, yes, it is a custom taxonomy term. Its like, "i want to display all hotels from paris" ( hotels = cpt, paris = custom tax). But before i make my query + while, i want to display a custom field, linked to paris. Is this more clear ?

Comment: ok, i arrive to get title with $taxonomy->post_title. Now i need to get my custom field and it will be perfect ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/#notes) on getting field data from fields attached to terms, you want to do something like this:

```
$term = get_queried_object();    
$area_singular = get_field( 'area_singular', $term );
```

Comment: yes, i know this method, but it returns nothing :/

Comment: it returns "null" to be exact (with var_dump())

Comment: That either means the `$term` is not a term object or the `area_singular` field isn't associated with the term you're requesting. I recommend taking a look at the database to see if this is the case.

Comment: Some of your comments have been a bit confusing, so I want to take a step back and make sure I understanding how you have this set up. In the admin, is the `area_singular` field able to be edited from the edit term page or from the edit post page?

Comment: From the taxonomy.

Comment: If the field is on the `/wp-admin/term.php` page, the issue is likely with the term object you're passing. I recommend inspecting the `$term` to see if the term object is right. I also recommend passing a value manually to see if that works, for example: `echo get_field( 'area_singular', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id );` .